# how to use threads with OOP in java

Tags: java, multithreading, oop

I am trying to run an object in java that creates a sign wave. I need to run this object over itself. I decided to use Threads to try to accomplish this. When I run it it gives me an error that says "tone can not be resolved" with the error occurring on the line that I define t1 and t2. I am very new to threads and any help with this would be much appreciated. Thank you for your time and help!

the code:

```
package dreamBeats;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine;

public class dreamBeatsClass extends Thread{

    static int length;
    static int wavelength;

   protected static final int SAMPLE_RATE = 16 * 1024;

//makes a sine wave buffer
   public static byte[] createSinWaveBuffer(double freq, int ms) {
       int samples = (int)((ms * SAMPLE_RATE) / 1000);
       byte[] output = new byte[samples];
           //
       double period = (double)SAMPLE_RATE / freq;
       for (int i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
           double angle = 2.0 * Math.PI * i / period;
           output[i] = (byte)(Math.sin(angle) * 127f);  }

       return output;
   }
// run the tone object
   public void run(){

        try {

        tone(length, wavelength);

        } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {}
      }
//create the threads and run them during one another
   public static void main(String[] args) throws LineUnavailableException, InterruptedException {
       Thread t1 = new Thread (new tone(1000, 400));
       Thread t2 = new Thread (new tone(1000, 500));
       t1.start();
       t2.start();
    }

   // create the sine wave
   public static void tone(int time, int wave) throws LineUnavailableException{
       final AudioFormat af = new AudioFormat(SAMPLE_RATE, 8, 1, true, true);
       SourceDataLine line = AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine(af);
       line.open(af, SAMPLE_RATE);
       line.start();

       boolean forwardNotBack = true;

       for(double freq = wave; freq <= wave*2;)  {
           byte [] toneBuffer = createSinWaveBuffer(freq, time);
           int count = line.write(toneBuffer, 0, toneBuffer.length);

           if(forwardNotBack)  {
               freq += wave/4;  
               forwardNotBack = false;  }
           else  {
               forwardNotBack = true;  
        }   }



       line.drain();
       line.close();    

       length = time;
       wavelength = wave;
   }

}
```

Comment: Java is case sensitive. No object start with lowercase. Probably you change tone by Tone... But I don't see any import with Tone.

Answer (score 0):

tone has to be a class. Also take a look at the Java style guide, I googled an old one for you: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html

The following code works for me:

```
    import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
    import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
    import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
    import javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine;

    public class VanuitStackoverflow extends Thread {



        // create the threads and run them during one another
        public static void main(String[] args) throws LineUnavailableException, InterruptedException {
            Thread t1 = new Thread(new Tone(1000, 400));
            Thread t2 = new Thread(new Tone(1000, 500));
            t1.start();
            t2.start();
        }
    }

    // create the sine wave
    class Tone implements Runnable {
        protected static final int SAMPLE_RATE = 16 * 1024;

        int length;
        int wavelength;

        // run the tone object
        public void run() {

            try {
                final AudioFormat af = new AudioFormat(SAMPLE_RATE, 8, 1, true, true);
                SourceDataLine line = AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine(af);
                line.open(af, SAMPLE_RATE);
                line.start();

                boolean forwardNotBack = true;

                for (double freq = wavelength; freq <= wavelength * 2;) {
                    byte[] toneBuffer = createSinWaveBuffer(freq, length);
                    int count = line.write(toneBuffer, 0, toneBuffer.length);

                    if (forwardNotBack) {
                        freq += wavelength / 4;
                        forwardNotBack = false;
                    } else {
                        forwardNotBack = true;
                    }
                }

                line.drain();
                line.close();

            } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
            }
        }

        Tone(int time, int wave) throws LineUnavailableException {
            this.length = time;
            this.wavelength = wave;
        }

        // makes a sine wave buffer
        public static byte[] createSinWaveBuffer(double freq, int ms) {
            int samples = (int) ((ms * SAMPLE_RATE) / 1000);
            byte[] output = new byte[samples];
            //
            double period = (double) SAMPLE_RATE / freq;
            for (int i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
                double angle = 2.0 * Math.PI * i / period;
                output[i] = (byte) (Math.sin(angle) * 127f);
            }

            return output;
        }

    }
```